# how to add tool to toolbox and set click event in textangular

Tags: angularjs

i currently working on a non profitable project and i'm using textangular module in my project and this is what i want to ask.
How to add tool in my textangular toolbox and how i can set click event to that tool?

Comment: Quite possibly you're being down voted due to this having an answer in the textAngular wiki: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar#creating-and-editing-tools

Answer (score 0):

Last time I am having a problem like yours,

I think first of all you, need to know that you are using textangular directives, and how to access it, maybe this link can help you understand how angular directive works (http://blog.xebia.com/2013/09/01/differences-between-providers-in-angularjs/)

as you can see in textangularsetup.js, there is a section where you register the element, so you can access it with decorator, maybe like this :

```
$provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions){
    // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating
    // register the tool with textAngular
    taRegisterTool('newcomponent', {
        iconclass: 'class_icon',
        tooltiptext: 'tooltip_text',
        action: function(){
            myaction(this);
        }
    });
    taOptions.toolbar[3].push('newComponent');
    return taOptions;
}]);
```

when you are in app.config,

Best Regards
Steve

Comment: nice, this code work flawlessly. but how to set the iconclass using external icon? thanks

Comment: to change the icon, please keep in mind Font-Awesome ≥ 4.x is used for the default icons on the toolbar(according to textangular requirement)